# Dart: update UI during long computation

Tags: dart, html5-canvas

I have a small dart script which I intend to use in the following way:

```
CanvasElement canvas;
void main() {
  canvas = querySelector('#canvas');
  querySelector('#start-button').onClick.listen((_) => work());
}

void work() {
  var state; // some state of the computation
  for (int i = 0; i < /*big number*/; i++) {
    // do some long computation
    render(state); // display intermediate result visualisation on canvas
  }
}

void render(var state) {
  canvas.context2D.... // draw on canvas based on state
}
```

that is listen for click on a button and on that click execute some long computation and from that computation display some intermediate results on the canvas live as the computation progresses.

However, this does not work - the canvas is updated only once after the whole computation completes.

Why is that? How should I arrange my code to work in a live, responsive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of solutions would be to put parts of your long computation into dart's [event loop](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/), i.e. queuing computation by waiting for a future it immediately return.

Please, see [sample on DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e5d1d0019a97f6aa111b).

But if you have lots of heavy computations, I think it would be better to start a new isolate and communicate with it about it's state.

**Update**

Here is almost, not exactly the same, work function, rewritten without using await, maybe it would be a bit clearer how it works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  new Future(()=>compute(i)).then((double result)=>render(i+result*50));
}
```

Here, we are actually creating 200 futures, queuing them into event loop (Future constructor does that), and registering a personal callback for each one.

Comment: Could you, please, explain the concept of computing in the event loop little bit more, maybe with a small example? Regarding the isolates, as I understood [this](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/#use-isolates-or-workers-if-necessary), it is not possible in a web app which is my case.

Comment: You have to remember that all is in a single thread in dart, and if you give no chance for dart's event loop to proceed, which was the case in your question, it just accumulated all requests, but started to run them only after your whole computation was done.

Comment: After we put part of your computation as a separate event in main loop (executing it in a Future), we're starting to wait (await) until dart compute all events  accumulated, including html redrawing and so on.

Comment: But await is only syntax sugar, just to make code more clear to read. We can rewrite that code using `.then()` callbacks, which is doing exactly the same.

Comment: I see how the solution works, but I'm not sure why the approach in the original question does not work. The code loops and updates the DOM each time around. Why do the DOM updates only become visible when the loop ends? See https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d50d5d490885b6e8979e to compare with the given solution.

Comment: Because inside your calls to canvas API Futures are created, but have no chance to be executed - first time you're exit your function is when everything calculated. Note my update on answer, there are 200 Futures created and function exits almost immediately. Everything else is executed from event loop, event by event, interleaving our futures with futures responsible for DOM updates.

Comment: Ok, in this case I understand the solution. But what if I have some complex computation (a genetic algorithm in my case) and sometimes in that algorithm (when I find new best-so-far solution) I want to display what I have at that time, i.e. I don't have a function that will return the result I want to display but sometimes I decide I want to display what I currently have.

Comment: Then first variant with async/await should work better. It's almost the same as updated, but guarantees order of execution,  and very close to template you provided. If your algorithm can be splitted in some parts,  they are good candidates to return futures you'll wait for.